# Trigger a Link once a new post is Published

Tags: posts

Is there Anyway to trigger a link once new post is Publish ?. My goal is to use it to ping sitemap

```
http://google.com/ping?sitemap=http://www.example.com/my_sitemap.xml
```

I simply don't want to set cron job for this. Please Gurus in the house is there anyway I can use theme function to achieve this ? I am new to wp coding Please.

Answer (score 1):

1- Just use jquery on form submit.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //default wordpress new post form id = #post
    $("#post").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://YOUR URL",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("CALL OK!");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("CALL FAILED!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

2- Put this code inside your theme: make new file, put the code above inside and save it in your theme dir. for example "this_is_my_scripts.js"

3- load your script file into admin. Put this code inside functions.php of your theme:

```
function custom_js_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/this_is_my_script.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_js_enqueue' );
```

Comment: The above Script did not Output anything on my wp admin dashboard.